# Way to include text in beamer presentations that is shown at handouts but not at the slides

Tags: latex, comments, beamer

is there some nice way in Beamer presentations (Latex) to include text (own remarks) that wouldn't be shown at the slides but would be printed with the handouts (little bit like the comments with Powerpoint?

br,
Touko

Comment: @Paul: LaTeX is *in* : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [beamer user guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf). This is discussed in Section 21. There's an example of exactly what you want on p191 (in v3.07).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to bother, i should have checked out the TOC there more carefully and find this section 21 : Creating Handouts and Lecture Notes...